# How can I open a command prompt in current folder with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

How can I open a command prompt in current folder with a keyboard shortcut in Windows 7?
Is there any way to implement this?
I think Autohotkey could do this, but don't know how.

Comment: Related: [Open command prompt window without holding shift](http://superuser.com/questions/240279/windows-open-command-prompt-window-without-holding-shift/240327#240327)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**Use this keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>**

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Menu</kbd> (alternatively, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>), (opens extended right-click menu in current folder)
2. <kbd>W</kbd> (selects "Open Command Window Here"),
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd> (activates selection; required since "New" is also selectable with <kbd>W</kbd>)

The <kbd>Menu</kbd> key refers to the special key introduced by Microsoft, usually to the right of the right <kbd>Win</kbd> key.

This shortcut is available on a default installation of Windows (7) without any 3rd party software.

---

**The AHK way. You just need to press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>** (or whatever you want to define it as.):

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
return

; Stuff to do when Windows Explorer is open
;
#IfWinActive ahk_class ExploreWClass|CabinetWClass

    ; create new text file
    ;
    #t::Send !fwt

    ; open 'cmd' in the current directory
    ;
    #c::
        OpenCmdInCurrent()
    return
#IfWinActive


; Opens the command shell 'cmd' in the directory browsed in Explorer.
; Note: expecting to be run when the active window is Explorer.
;
OpenCmdInCurrent()
{
    ; This is required to get the full path of the file from the address bar
    WinGetText, full_path, A

    ; Split on newline (`n)
    StringSplit, word_array, full_path, `n

    ; Find and take the element from the array that contains address
    Loop, %word_array0%
    {
        IfInString, word_array%A_Index%, Address
        {
            full_path := word_array%A_Index%
            break
        }
    }  

    ; strip to bare address
    full_path := RegExReplace(full_path, "^Address: ", "")

    ; Just in case - remove all carriage returns (`r)
    StringReplace, full_path, full_path, `r, , all


    IfInString full_path, \
    {
        Run,  cmd /K cd /D "%full_path%"
    }
    else
    {
        Run, cmd /K cd /D "C:\ "
    }
}
```

As a bonus, the script above also creates a new text file with this shortcut: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Credit to: [Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98597/best-autohotkey-macros/100648#100648)

Comment: ah, shift-menu is nice.

Comment: How do you use this script exactly?

Comment: @Jonathan: Install Auto-HotKey (http://www.autohotkey.com/). Copy the script contents to the AutoHotkey.ahk file. (probably in %USERPROFILE%\documents\\) Restart Auto-Hotkey.

Comment: This was the only working solution out of all the AutoHotkey snippets I found on the web. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: any way to get an elevated console?

Comment: Also doesn't work for the desktop, if you count that as a current folder...

Comment: @boleslaw.smialy : maybe it is you're not using an American/English version of Windows? (With the Italian wersion you should use 'f' instead of 'w' for instance)

Comment: May I ask you, just of curiosity, why you changed original script in this line: `Loop, %word_array0%...` instead of keeping original `full_path = %word_array1%`?

Comment: @johnc.j.: Honestly, it was so long ago I don't even recall modifying the original script. The difference my version checks all array elements for the address, instead of just assuming the address is in the first element.

Comment: There is a much neater version of AHK script down. (by using `win.LocationURL`, much easier to parse)

Answer (score 158):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For more details see blog post [here](http://choorucode.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/windows-keyboard-shortcut-to-command-prompt-of-current-directory/).

Comment: nice! the other option doesn't seem to show the "open command window here" option unless you right-click on a folder - inside the folder, it doesn't show

Comment: This opens a cmd window, but it does not open one at the current directory. The same thing can be accomplished with win+r, cmd

Comment: Note - You do not need to press Alt+d for this to work. All I had to do in Windows 7 was type cmd into the path of windows explorer and press enter. Alt+d just automatically selects the current path.

Comment: `Ctrl+L` is an alternative.

Comment: How to open the same as administrator from current folder

Comment: Additional note to that. Whatever you execute in that search bar will be treated as a normal CMD command. For example I can fast execute a g++ command.

Answer (score 43):

the native way to do something similar in windows7 is to hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> while pressing the right mouse onto the folder you want to "command prompt" to and a new menu item will appear in your context menu offering you exactly that: "open command prompt here".

[image]

if you want pure keyboard action then you have to do this:

- open `regedit`
- go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd` and rename the `Extended` key to `Extended_save`
- go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmd` and rename the `Extended key to`Extended_save`

this adds the "open command window here" entry to the context menu permanently. you can trigger this entry by pressing:

- <kbd>alt</kbd>
- let go, context menu opens
- press the "underscored" character of the "open command window here" entry or go down with your cursor keys and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

the name of the menu entry is labled according to the language of your OS.

an alternative route is to do this:

- open the folder you want in the command prompt via the explorer
- <kbd>f4</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>
- <kbd>win</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
- `cmd /k cd` <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>

which grabs the current path from the address bar of explorer and executes `cmd /k cd PATH`. with autohotkeys you can do the same, but i do not know autohotkeys.

Answer (score 11):

From [how-to-open-cmd-in-current-folder-by-shortcut-windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/1106976/how-to-open-cmd-in-current-folder-by-shortcut-windows-10)

If you are using Windows 8/10, there is a faster and original way :

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>

Just three key and type twice , without help of another program.

Comment: Thanks. Because of your tip, I was able to discover Alt + F, M A is to open command prompt in Admin mode. :)

Comment: Thanks! In the German version of Windows is the hot key ALT + D, E

Answer (score 3):

As of the latest Windows 10 update, Leftium's answer's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd> method no longer works. However, a small modification can present a workaround, albeit with a few more keystrokes.

The problem is that Command Prompt is no longer available in the Extended Right-Click Menu. Instead, you now have Windows Powershell.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> opens up Windows Powershell in the target folder. Once in Windows Powershell, type `cmd` then press <kbd>Enter.</kbd>

This will give you access to Command Prompt within Windows Powershell.

P.S.

Ashwin Nanjappa's method of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, type `cmd` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> works. However, it is elegant only if you do not intend to return to the Windows Explorer window to continue navigating among directories. Unfortunately the method brings your cursor in Windows Explorer away from the main window and requires a number of <kbd>Tab</kbd> keystrokes to get it back to where you can navigate folders using the arrow keys. This can be frustrating as there is limited visual confirmation when you are pressing those <kbd>Tab</kbd> keystrokes.

Whereas Windows Powershell does work in most ways identically to Command Prompt, I have encountered at least one case in which Windows Powershell was erroneously misreading my @tags (when I was generating javadocs) and not producing the desired result. By typing `cmd` then Enter within Windows Powershell, you can use Command Prompt instead which overcomes such issues.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler AHK script than the one in the selected question

```
#c::cmdHere()

cmdHere() {
    If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") || WinActive("ahk_class ExploreWClass") {
        WinHWND := WinActive()
        For win in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
            If (win.HWND = WinHWND) {
                dir := SubStr(win.LocationURL, 9) ; remove "file:///"
                dir := RegExReplace(dir, "%20", " ")
                Break
            }
    }
    Run, cmd, % dir ? dir : A_Desktop
}
```

source from here : https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=5796

Answer (score 1):

AutoHotKey script to open command prompt using [@Ashwin's method](https://superuser.com/questions/205359/how-to-open-command-prompt-in-current-folder-by-keyboard-shortcut/289459#289459)

Open Powershell console using <kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>

```
#P::
{
    Send !D
    Send powershell
    Send {Enter}    
    return
}
```

Open command prompt using <kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>

```
#C::
{
    Send !D
    Send CMD
    Send {Enter}    
    return
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't open the cmd in the open folder but in `system32`

Answer (score 1):

How about to use the PowerShell `OpenHere` [module](https://github.com/KUTlime/PowerShell-Open-Here-Module)?

Run PowerShell with elevated permissions and type:

```
Install-Module OpenHere
Set-OpenHereShortcut -ShortcutType:CMD
```

#### Disclaimer:

I'm a developer of this module.

Answer (score 1):

This utilizes autohotkey.exe. Save this with `.ahk` extension.

If explorer.exe is the active window, open cmd.exe using the active `PATH`.

If explorer.exe is not the active window, open cmd.exe to `C:\Windows\System32`.

Run this by itself or call it with a master script using `#Include PATH\TO\BELOW\SCRIPT.ahk`

```
; ###################
; #  OPEN CMD HERE  #
; ###################

!c::_OpenCMDHere()

_OpenCMDHere()
{
    GroupAdd, _GroupCMDHere, ahk_exe cmd.exe
    GroupClose, _GroupCMDHere, A
    If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") {
        _WinHWND := WinActive()
        For Win in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
            If (Win.HWND = _WinHWND)
                _pwd := SubStr(Win.LocationURL, 9)
                _pwd := RegExReplace(_pwd, "%20", " ")
                _pwd := RegExReplace(_pwd, "/", "\")
            Run, "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /T:0A /D /K PROMPT $P$G$_$G & PUSHD "%_pwd%",, Max, WinPID
            WinWait, ahk_pid %WinPID%
            WinActivate, ahk_pid %WinPID%
    }
    Else {
        Run, "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /T:0A /D /K PROMPT $P$G$_$G & PUSHD "C:\Windows\System32\",, Max, WinPID
        WinWait, ahk_pid %WinPID%
        WinActivate, ahk_pid %WinPID%
    }
}
Return
```

Update:

This is even simpler and is in line with what user MagTun said above. This also fixed path issues that occur when the '&' symbol is in the file path.

```
!c::_OpenCMDHere()

_OpenCMDHere()
{
    If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
        _WinHWND := WinActive()
        For Win in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
            If (Win.HWND = _WinHWND)
            {
                _pwd := SubStr(Win.LocationURL, 9)
                _pwd := RegExReplace(_pwd, "%20", " ")
                _pwd := RegExReplace(_pwd, "%26", "&") ; Fix issues with '&' in the path
                _pwd := RegExReplace(_pwd, "/", "\")
            }
    Run, "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /T:0A /D /K PROMPT $P$G$_$G, % _pwd ? _pwd : "C:\Windows\System32\", Max
}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a german languaged Windows version you can do this:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> opens a menu where you can select a few other things besides the cmd

Comment: Alt+D select the Address Bar, not a menu

Comment: Seems to only work on German languaged Windows versions

Comment: Edit your answer then I can remove the down vote

Comment: `Alt+D` works in English Windows. An alternative shortcut is `Ctrl+L`. A similar but not equivalent solution is `F4`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1-**Just open **File Explorer**

**Step 2-** **Get inside the folder** where you want **open cmd**.

**Step 3-**After getting inside that folder **type cmd in Address bar** and **hit enter**. (Address bar is located near Search bar in the file explorer)
Boom. CMD will open in current location.

Hope you like the answer. Thankyou every much.

Answer (score -1):

For AHK, following is my binding:

```
#c::
Run, C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
return
```

This does not open current folder, but it is handy.