# Launch apps or run commands on Windows via shortcuts

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to register shortcuts on Windows 7 so that regardless where you are looking (Desktop, a folder etc) the shortcut gets "heard" and the appropriate action is performed.

For example, creating a shortcut in the System32 folder which will work if you use Run with the shortcut's name, will not work if you set a key combination when focus is set on the Desktop for example.

Is there a native way of registering top-level shortcuts or even an application for enabling this?

Example of things I want keyboard shortcuts for:

- open a specific folder like %path%
- create a new .js file in the current folder
- launch an application eventually with its path set to the current location if the app supports this (e.g. command prompt)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

For instance, let's say you want the shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to launch `MyScript`. Install AutoHotKey, copy what follows to the AutoHotkey.ahk file, and restart AutoHotKey:

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
return

; Stuff to do when Windows Explorer is open
;
#IfWinActive ahk_class ExploreWClass|CabinetWClass

    #s::
        LaunchMyScriptInCurrent()
    return
#IfWinActive


; Launches a custom script in the directory browsed in Explorer.
; Note: expecting to be run when the active window is Explorer.
;
LaunchMyScriptInCurrent()
{
    ; This is required to get the full path of the file from the address bar
    WinGetText, full_path, A

    ; Split on newline (`n)
    StringSplit, word_array, full_path, `n
    ; Take the first element from the array
    full_path = %word_array1%   

    ; strip to bare address
    full_path := RegExReplace(full_path, "^Address: ", "")

    ; Just in case - remove all carriage returns (`r)
    StringReplace, full_path, full_path, `r, , all

    IfInString full_path, \
    {
        Run, C:\Path\To\MyScript "%full_path%"
    }
    else
    {
        Run, C:\Path\To\MyScript "C:\ "
    }
}
```

Inspired from those two answers:

1. https://superuser.com/a/205368/118346
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/100648/1005455

Comment: Thanks for that. I take it there's no simple way to do this, eventually with a GUI? Editing scripts is better than nothing, but I don't want to waste time learning how to do that when a GUI would be so much faster.