# Create folder and subfolders if need at once

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer

May be my topic name is unclear ant that's why I couldn't find a solution on the internet.

I want to have an ability to create a folder from Explorer with an ability to create subfolders automatically if specified folder name contains characters '\'. For example: I type the following name:

```
folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2
```

And after pressing Enter it creates folder with a name `folder1` (if such folder doesn't exist yet)
and folder with a name `subfolder1` in folder `folder1` (if such folder doesn't exist yet)
and folder with a name `subfolder2` in folder `subfolder1` (if such folder doesn't exist yet).

Total Commander has such ability. But when I try to type that path with slashes in Explorer it tells me that folder can't contain such characters.

Is there a some Explorer extension that adds such functionality? For example, I right-click on a free space in an Explorer window folder and select context-menu item like "Create folder and subfolders" and it gives me a way for typing new path with slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use command prompt (cmd.exe) and than type

> md folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2

It will create folders, and subfolders. 
if you are in folder C:\Users\Administrator it will create 
C:\Users\Administrator\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2

p.s. Typing cmd in windows explorer address bar will open cmd at current directory.

Comment: It's inconvenient every time to open cmd.exe when you need to create a folder in Explorer... I want to find the quickest way to do this.

Comment: I dont find it inconvenient, that is the soulituin that I would use. winKey+r to open RUN and then type in cmd, and there you go. Or you can always add custom shortcut to cmd.exe. Or you can even add it to right click menu and use it from Windows Explorer

Comment: OK. Let's compare your solution and solution, which I'm trying to find: Mine: 1. Right-Click on Explorer window; 2. Choose something like "Create folder"; 3. Type name and press enter. Yours: 1. First of all we need to copy path to folder where we want to create another folder with subfolders; 2. Open cmd.exe; 3. Typing `mkdir "` 4. Right-Click on cmd; 5. Choose `Paste`; 6. Then continue typing folder for creation and finish it with `"` and press Enter; 7. Close already unnecessary cmd window. As you see, there are 7 steps against 3. May be I don't know cmd so well as you and missed something?

Comment: You can type cmd in adress bar, or make custom shortuct. You dont need to copy/paste because your 2. and 3. you will do them in cmd , type name and press enter. You can add http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/StExBar.html exstension so you will just click and open cmd, or you can look this post http://superuser.com/questions/205359/how-can-i-open-a-command-prompt-in-current-folder-with-a-keyboard-shortcut. And open cmd at current position.

Comment: I didn't know that typing cmd in Explorer address bar opens console with current directory. It's great! Thanks!

Comment: I have updated answer so other users will know to.