# The fastest way to open cmd in current folder by shortcut (windows 8/10)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I used to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + `mouse right click` to open cmd in current folder.
It is the fastest way I think, there are some relate solution in superuser:

In [how-can-i-open-a-command-prompt-in-current-folder-with-a-keyboard-shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/205359/how-can-i-open-a-command-prompt-in-current-folder-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Menu</kbd>(or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>), <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   need enter 4 key, and type 3 time.(I think it worked on all windows(at least from 7 to 10 I have tested)
2. **The AHK way. You just need to press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>** (please see detail in above question), but you need install `ANK`, paste script and set it in windows startup.

Is there any easier and faster way to do such thing in Windows 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## There only need three key in windows 8/10:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>

Just three key and type twice , without help of another program.

---

## For somenoe feedback that shortcut not work:

I would show you how to find the correct key here

*note: my system lang is Chinese, but layout is same, you wouldn't miss it.*

1. You need open a folder

   **Note**:`Open command prompt` option may be grayed out at some place, thanks for [**@PIMP_JUICE_IT**'s answer, click to see detail.](https://superuser.com/questions/1106976/the-fastest-way-to-open-cmd-in-current-folder-by-shortcut-windows-8-10/1106994#1106994).

   You need enter a real folder, special folder such as `Favorite` would not work, because it doesn't have a real path, I have a try and find:

   green folder is not real folder(shortcut not work), but folder in red zone is Ok

   [image]
2. press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you would see the hotkey of `File Button`(top left window)

   [image]

   It is <kbd>F</kbd> in my system. `F` maybe different in you system, just replace it.
3. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>(replace <kbd>F</kbd> with <kbd>Your system File key</kbd>) , you would see the hotkey mark too.

   [image]

   <kbd>P</kbd> is `cmd` shortcut here(replace <kbd>P</kbd> with the <kbd>Your system cmd key</kbd> you see)

Then just do:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Your system File key</kbd>, <kbd>Your system cmd key</kbd>

**PS: If still not work**, please check you shortcut binding, there must be some program take the control.

Comment: Are you sure this is working by default? It's not working for me. Alt+F does nothing, so if I press P it just searches for P.

Comment: +1 from me, your solution works just fine. . . look over my answer below and the section I added labeled: **CAUTION: Issues with ALT + F + P (and other methods)** --this may explain what people are experiencing.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Thanks for the tip. How to add the reference link to your answer?

Comment: This was working for me, but with the Windows 10 ugrade to Version 1703, the 'Open Command Prompt' entry in the file menu is now gone.

Comment: now in Windows 10 there's only power shell in the menu

Answer (score 5):

### Another Default All Keyboard Method

Once in the current folder with Windows Explorer, press <kbd>**ALT**</kbd>+<kbd>**D**</kbd>, type in **`CMD`** and press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>

---

### CAUTION: Issues with <kbd>**ALT**</kbd> + <kbd>**F**</kbd> + <kbd>**P**</kbd> (and other methods)

**The This PC, Quick Access, and other special views in File Explorer is the real issue**

1. It seems if you open **Windows Explorer\File Explorer** and by default it opens **This PC** then the **Open command prompt** option is grayed out and actually pressing the <kbd>**P**</kbd> key at this point does nothing if this is the case. This seems to be an issue for other **File Explorer** special views as well such as **Quick Access**.

   [image]
2. When pressing <kbd>**ALT**</kbd>+<kbd>**D**</kbd>, typing in **`CMD`** and pressed <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> when on **This PC** (and **Quick Access**) via **File Explorer**, it opens up the command prompt in the **`C:\WINDOWS\system32`** directory.

   [image]

Comment: For me, the C in CMD already closes the current Explorer Window, whereas E would open CMD (and P opens Powershell)

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to open a cmd in a specific Windows folder location is:
typing `cmd` into the folder URL and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Here is a screenprint to further illustrate it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Easy way with 3 keys, no extra settings needed:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>

---

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will open up the menu in Windows Explorer with mnemonics enabled and shown.

Then just press the mnemonic key for CMD, which will open it immediately. In my case it's <kbd>E</kbd>, but it *might* be different for you, depenending on your system language.

Comment: What's your system language?

Comment: German, E for 'Eingabeaufforderung', a horrible word for command prompt.

Comment: after Alt+D I have to press c (for cmd) then down arrow and enter to open it

Answer (score 0):

If you can slightly tweak the "Open command window here" verb, you can save 2 keystrokes. **Assumes** no files are currently selected in the folder.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\Shell\cmd]
@="Open co&mmand window here"
"Extended"=-
```

This REG fix does 2 things:

1. Removes the string value named `Extended` so that you don't have to use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key access the command.
2. Changes the accelerator to letter `m` instead of `w`. As no other menu items use `m`, pressing <kbd>Menu</kbd> key + `m` launches Command Prompt window, without having to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. (This works at least in English language versions of Windows.)

If you change your mind and want to revert back the settings to defaults, use this REG file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\Shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
```