# How to launch a command prompt window in a specific folder

Tags: windows-10, command-line

From Windows Explorer I want to launch a command-prompt window with the working directory the current folder in Explorer.

So far I:

- copy the path from the explorer navigation bar
- Windows+R: cmd to launch a cmd prompt
- cd /d CTRL+V

But there must be a way to improve on this somewhat? Preferably without installing any extensions.

I'm running a pretty standard Windows 10 setup, slightly different versions across different machines so something that is standard would be best.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to open a folder from Windows Explorer in cmd.exe under Windows 10 with one shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/1519562/way-to-open-a-folder-from-windows-explorer-in-cmd-exe-under-windows-10-with-one)

Comment: Mr. Boy, when in the Windows Explorer folder, go to the address bar, type CMD, press enter, and bam.... cmd open from that folder location.... Note this doesn't work for UND paths though, just drive letter mapped folders.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT that's awesome and not the asnwer others seem to be sharing... nice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The fastest way to open cmd in current folder by shortcut (windows 8/10)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106976/the-fastest-way-to-open-cmd-in-current-folder-by-shortcut-windows-8-10)

Comment: you can just write `cmd` in your navigation bar and cmd will open in the current folder

Answer (score 1):

You can hold down the SHIFT key and right click in blank space in the folder. There will be an option for "Open CMD Window Here." 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me a **[duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/1519562/way-to-open-a-folder-from-windows-explorer-in-cmd-exe-under-windows-10-with-one)**, where several options are answered.

Anyway, take a look at this simple option...

---

---

- So, save this code as file.**[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**, and run or click **(need admin rights)**.

  ---

```bat
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00;Command Prompt Here[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]@="Command Prompt Here"[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
cls & echo/ & "%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" import "%~f0" & "%__APPDIR__%timeout" -1
```

---

- This is the reg part of hybrid with **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file:

  ---

```bat
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Command Prompt Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

---

- You get this menu context: **`Command Prompt Here`**
- You don't need additional startup script or holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and **Right-Click**.