# How can I open a command prompt with administrative privilege in current folder with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have seen [How can I open a command prompt in current folder with a keyboard shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/205359/how-can-i-open-a-command-prompt-in-current-folder-with-a-keyboard-shortcut) 
and I know these ways like Press `Alt+D`, type `cmd` and press `Enter` Or pressing `shift + click` open in command prompt 
but how can I open with **administrative privilege?**

### **Edit**

Adam's answer is perfect and, along with that, 
I also found a shell extension which can do that called [ContextConsole](http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen).

[image: screenshot for ContextConsole]

This is opensource and supports both 32 and 64 bit

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should remove the edit from the question and add an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create new shortcut with `cmd.exe /kcd /dd:\some_folder` as target, go to shortcut properties, set shortcut key, go to advanced and set run as administrator.

For clarification:

`cmd /k` Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt
`cd /d` changing current folder and drive

Comment: Do I put my directory in `d:\my_dir` portion ? If yes, it doesn't work. what does the `/kcd` and `/d` stands for ?

Comment: yes, put your full patch directory after cd /d, if it  contains spaces then put it in double quotes.

Comment: works perfect !

Comment: @AdamSilenko Superb! You seem to be extremely good...by any means would you be able to answer my question here : http://superuser.com/questions/1152477/setting-folder-wallpaper-in-external-hard-disk-using-desktop-ini Thanks in advance