# Setting folder wallpaper in external hard disk using desktop.ini

Tags: windows-7, desktop.ini

For my external hard disk, I can give any folder a background by making a **desktop.ini** file with the following code :

```
[AveFolder]
Recursive=1
ShadowedText=1
IconArea_Image=G:\TV Series\Sense8\.png
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=G:\TV Series\Sense8\jsvndsdjvu.ico,0
```

(Forgive my use of .png file without name and that randomly named icon file)

However note that I am using the fact that my external hard disk is my **G:** and so if I give my hard disk to someone who has hard disk as **H:** my folders will not show their full colours. I have been searching the net for the past few hours with no result. The closest I got was using CLSID values instead of drive names but that didn't work out (maybe I was using wrong CLSID values or maybe using CLSID values in **desktop.ini** requires some sprecial code).

Ok so can anyone help me how to make my **desktop.ini** file so that it shows the folder background no matter what drive letter it gets. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use dynamic image location:

`IconArea_Image=/TV Series/Sense8/.png`

propaby Windows 8 and above do not support this

Comment: Didn't work...Windows 7

Comment: you can install additional app (like [AveFolderBG](http://qpdownload.com/avefolderbg/) ) if you want to see background

Comment: No, I can see background with G:\TV Series\Sense8\.png but I can't see background with G:\TV Series\Sense8\.png ...maybe dynamic image location doesn't work with 7? (My windows 7 isn't genuine btw)

Answer (score 1):

Use relative paths, like this:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=\TV Series\Sense8\jsvndsdjvu.ico,0
```

See also: [Variable Path for external hard disk](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/variable-path-for-external-hard-disk/ad97096d-7df1-498c-ac8c-8bedace9b718)

Comment: Tried it...didn't work out.